# Lotto Probabilities

Tags: probability

NY State Lotto works by "$6$ winning numbers and a bonus number are randomly selected from $59$ numbered balls".  The $3rd$ Prize level states that you have matched $5$ numbers, and not the bonus number.  Your chances of winning the 3rd Prize level is $1:144,414.98$.  ([NY State Lotto Chances Page](http://nylottery.ny.gov/wps/portal/Home/Lottery/Home/Jackpot+Games/LOTTO/Lotto+-+Chances+of+Winning))  It has higher odds for a $\$1$ play, but that parts not explained well.

Anyway, does the lotto work in the same manner as a deck of cards?  Can we say that if I were to purchase $5$ unique tickets, my odds of winning $3rd$ prize level with at least one of my tickets would be $\frac{5}{144,414.98}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Technically, `P(A|B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A&B)`, so you'd have to subtract out the probability of winning more than once. If you choose nearly identical numbers on the 5 tickets, this could make a significant difference.

Comment: So, even if not exact, would you say that it is roughly or approximately $\frac{5}{144,414.98}$?

Comment: Yes, provided you don't choose the similar or overlapping numbers on the 5 tickets.

Comment: Interesting.  I should have specified that the numbers would be random, but with over 45 million possible combinations, odds are likely that there wouldn't be much overlap.  Ok, thanks

Comment: Well, 5 tickets with 6 numbers each is 30 numbers total out of 59 possible numbers, so, not a trivial chance of at least one number matching across the tickets.

Comment: Anyone know if there is a formula I can use to get a more exact calculation?